# There is a isSomething() lib for Java?

Tags: java, definition

I want to know if there is a lib for Java with implementations like: `isTemperature()`, `isPercentual()`, `isDistanceUnit()`, `isWeightUnit()`,`isProperName()`, `isDate()`, `isYear()`, `isPhone()`, `isLocation()` and what more can be defined.

Not only units are for my interest, but all type of classifications that is possible to do, be number or word.

This will be used to classify words in a text.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want to do? It's vague

Comment: @Nishant I want to get all the words of a text and classify it in the most categories possible.

Comment: What input do you expect? For example, would it just be just a number or a string comprising the unit: `100` or one of `"100 °C"`, `"100 °F"` or `"100 K"` for a temperature?

Comment: @Bruno The second case, the number with the unit. An input can be two or more things at same type, and there is no problems if units are equals for diferents types of measures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I am aware of. However, you can still create methods yourself that do the same thing...

### `isTemperature()`

```
boolean isTemperature(String check) {
    char[] letters = check.toCharArray();
    if (check.indexOf("°").equals((letters.length - 1)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

### `isPercentual()`

```
boolean isPercentual(String check) {
    try {
        double verify = Double.parseDouble(check);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] numbers = check.toCharArray();
    if (check.indexOf("%").equals(numbers.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

### `isDistanceUnit()`

```
boolean isDistanceUnit(String check, boolean customary) {
    String[] customaryUnits = {"mi","yd","ft","in"};
    String[] metricUnits = {"mm","cm","dm","m","km"};
    if (customary) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= customaryUnits.length; i++) {
            if (check.toLowerCase().contains(customaryUnits[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= metricUnits.length; i++) {
            if (check.toLowerCase().contains(metricUnits[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

### `isWeightUnit()`

```
boolean isWeightUnit(String check, boolean customary) {
    String[] customaryUnits = {"lb","oz","T"};
    String[] metricUnits = {"kg"}; //I'm sorry that's all I know :(
    if (customary) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= customaryUnits.length; i++) {
            if (check.toLowerCase().contains(customaryUnits[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= metricUnits.length; i++) {
            if (check.toLowerCase().contains(metricUnits[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

### `isProperName()`

```
boolean isProperName(String check) {
    char[] letters = check.toCharArray();
    String[] capLetters = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    for (int i = 0; i <= capLetters.length; i++) {
        if (letters[0].equals(capLetters[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### `isDate()`

**UPDATE:** Now I can give you this one. A quick note before I do, though. Add these lines at the beginning of your code or this method won't work.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
boolean isDate(String check) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    if (check.trim().length != dateFormat.toPattern().length) {
        return false;
    }
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {  
        dateFormat.parse(check.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

### `isYear()`

```
boolean isYear(String check) {
    try {
        int verify = Integer.parseInt(check);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] verify2 = check.toCharArray();
    if ((verify2.length).equals(4)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

### `isPhone()`

You haven't really said what kind of phone number you want to check for. I'm guessing you want one in this form (865-867-5309).

```
boolean isPhone(String check) {
    float firstHyphen = check.indexOf("-");
    char[] numbers = check.toCharArray();
    float check2 = numbers.length / 3;
    if (firstHypen.equals(check2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

### `isLocation()`

I apologize I can't give you this one right now. :(

### `isEmail()`

```
boolean isEmail(String check) {
    String[] emailDomains = {".com",".net",".org"};
    String[] emailProviders = {"gmail","yahoo","hotmail","aol","tds","comcast","charter","peoplepc"}; //add more if you want
    char[] check2 = check.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <= emailProviders.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= emailDomains.length; x++) {
            if ((check.indexOf(emailDomains[x]).equals(check2.length)) && (check.indexOf(emailProviders[i]).equals(check2.length - emailDomains[x].toCharArray().length)) {
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

You can add more units for the `isDistanceUnit()` and `isWeightUnit()` methods if you wish. If you need any more methods or if you have any questions, just ask. :)

Comment: There...even if there hadn't been such a library, there is one now. :)

Comment: Yes, this it's I was supposing to do. Very impressive.

Comment: @fireshadow52 Chris answer showed me a thing that I probably will use in my software, so the answer that it gave me was useful for my project. Your answer it's an example of what I asked (and what I asked maybe not be the right choice) and can be valuable for most people that need use this, so yes, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @fireshadow52 If you are interested doing more of this job, do an isIniatilism/Acronym(), isEmail(), isWebProtocol() and what more you guess you want do.

Comment: Fair enough. Check out Apple's LSI classification code too, it's how the mail app on iPhone and OS X picks out addresses, phone numbers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Is there an equivalent library in a language you have experience with already?

I can't think of many applications where you'd need to check for the presence of all of those formats in a single data source but I'd use regular expressions to do the job.

**EDIT:**

If your data is heterogeneous and you want to just work out what it is, you probably need some kind of classifier. Try [jBNC](http://jbnc.sourceforge.net/) or [classifier4j](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I develop in Java. I tought about RegEx, but will be a large number of validations, so before I code my regex, is better to try find something done.

Comment: Some of these methods are very location-specific. Do you want to know if a telephone number from the UK or the USA is valid for instance?

Comment: Yes, some are very specific, so only some can be validated, not alls in the world. The same goes for another items. For example, temperatures, only the most common (Celsis, Fahrenheit, Kelvin)

Comment: I will take a loot at these Bayesians classifiers. Maybe they can solve my problem, but these two examples are not updated a long time (2004 and 2005). They are good? There is something more recent?

Comment: There are numerous classifier libraries to choose from, many cross-platform. Try googling for more. Without looking at the raw data I'd guess that some kind of Naive Bayes or LSI classifier would satisfy your requirements provided you have enough example data to train it with. Whichever one you decide to use is up to you, and it'll probably be the one you find easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the first two links that appear above yours:

http://www.google.com/search?q=java+units+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

What you really need is some ontology to add a great deal of context.  Check out [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/) and [Cyc](http://www.cyc.com/opencyc).   What you're asking for goes far beyond mere validation and regular expressions.  After re-reading your question, it sounds like you want to read a document and somehow have your parser pick out tokens that match those units and discern what they are from the context.  If that hits the mark, you've got a very difficult problem on your hands.  It's much more along the lines of natural language processing.

Comment: Above me? I don't saw these links, but thanks, I will take a look. But is important that is not only units I'm interested, though words are less classifiable than numbers.

Comment: Yes, yours was the third link returned by Google.  The citations deal with units; you may need something else to supplement.  My point is that a simple Google search would have gotten you something to go on, and faster than reading and downvoting responses here.

Comment: It's barely worth the time it would take to look.  I'm not worried about a negative vote.